# random position of elements inside parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have floating RANDOM elements inside DIV, varying LEFT and TOP position inside parent `<div class="main"></div>`. How to calculate and set LEFT and TOP positions mathematically in javascript/jQuery so any random element will NOT go beyond boundary defined parent

HTML :

```
<div class="main"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('.main').append('<div class="box"></div>');
}
$( '.box' ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).css({
    left : ((Math.random() * $('.main').width())),
    top : ((Math.random() * $('.main').height()))
  });
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/iahmadraza/u5y1zthv/

Thank you

Comment: You have to remove the amount of width/height of the element itself.
left : ((Math.random() * ($('.main').width()-$(this).width()))),
top : ((Math.random() * ($('.main').height()-$(this).height())))

Comment: [`function getRnd(min, max)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) with `min = 0` and `max = (main.width - box.width)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.box` elements are fixed at `100px` height and width, so to achieve what you need just remove that dimension from the possible random value maximum:

```
$(this).css({
  left: Math.random() * ($('.main').width() - $(this).width()),
  top: Math.random() * ($('.main').height() - $(this).height())
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u5y1zthv/1/)

Comment: how can i set them not to overlap?

Comment: Perform some collision detection after randomly generating a position. If a collision is detected generate a new position and repeat.